# Multiple posts in Nodejs with SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, api

I've created a small express server using Nodejs and SQL Server (stored procedure) and I'm currently able to handle a single post request.

I need to incorporate an multiple post request, which would allow me to register a multiple row in the table

```
router.route("/").post(function(req, res) {
    var list = req.body;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list[i]);
      conn
        .connect()
        .then(pool => {
          return (
            pool
              .request()
              //.input("PreSaleBoMID", sql.Int, req.body.PreSaleBoMID)
              .input("CodSAP", sql.Int, list[i].CodigoSAP)
              .input("Manufacturer", sql.VarChar, list[i].Fabricante)
              .input("PartNro", sql.VarChar, list[i].ParteNo)
              .input("Description", sql.VarChar, list[i].Descripcion)
              .input("QtyImplement", sql.Int, list[i].CantaImplementar)
              .input("QtySpare", sql.Int, list[i].CantRepuestos)
              .input("AmountValue", sql.Money, list[i].ValorUnitario)
              .input("AmountTotal", sql.Money, list[i].ValorTotal)
              .input("Currency", sql.VarChar, list[i].Moneda)
              .input("Type", sql.VarChar, list[i].Tipo)
              //.input("Observation", sql.VarChar, req.body.Observation)
              .output("NewID", sql.Int)
              .execute("Project.Usp_InsertPreSaleBoMDetail")
          );
        })
        .then(recordset => {
          res.send(recordset.output);
          conn.close();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          conn.close();
        });
    }
});
```